# builtins.TypeError TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i have tried 100 times i do not know what is wrong with this code. somebody please help me to sort out this issue or tell me what i am doing wrong to below code.

Every time i receive:

> builtins.TypeError TypeError: getCategoryItems() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'cat_id'

Code:

```
@app.route('/')
def getAllItems():
    return redirect(url_for('getCategoryItems', category_name='ab', cat_id=1))


@app.route('/<string:category_name>/items/')
def getCategoryItems(category_name, cat_id):
    id = cat_id;
    items = session.query(Item).filter_by(category_id=id).all()
    output = ''
    for item in items:
        output += item.title + '</br>'
    return output
```

Comment: try `url_for('getCategoryItems', {'category_name':'ab', 'cat_id':1})`

Comment: You're trying to get the category items by name and id. Is this right? Normally, I would say an id is enough.

Comment: no i am getting items by id but i have to show category's name as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass `category_name`, you only need the category id. The category name should be contained in each of the item fetched from the database.

You're getting an error because `cat_id` is not defined when the function `def getCategoryItems(category_name, cat_id)` is called.

I would suggest, however, if you want to really get all items to just use:

```
@app.route('/')
def getAllItems():
  items = session.query(Item).all()
  ...
```

For more info, have a look at the [flask-sqlalchemy docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/queries/).